# C# Button visible change when button cliked

Tags: c#

i tried to do this(**mine field**) but i cant visible = false any button when im clicked that.
by the way this.visible = false is going to visible form -.-

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Size = new Size(541, 537);
        for (int j = 24; j < ClientSize.Height; j += 25)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < ClientSize.Width; i += 25)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Width = 25;
                btn.Height = 25;
                btn.Location = new Point(i, j);
                btn.Click += btn_Click;
                Controls.Add(btn);

            }
        }

    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //When i clicked anyone of them that comes be invisible,
    }
```

thx for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control that fired the event is stored in `sender` - cast it back to a `Button`.

```
void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;

    button.Hide();
}
```

Alternatively, if that's all you're doing in the event, you could define it in a single line like this:

```
btn.Click += delegate { btn.Hide(); };
```